Why did Yitzchak avinu need to go through the Akkeida?
Discussions of Avraham's trials explain how each test revealed to Avraham and the whole world a certain new quality of faith that he had. The Midrash Bereshis Rabba 56:8 also quoted by Rashi on Bereshis 22:12 seems to say that the Akkeida test was also supposed to be a test for Yitzchak:

אָמַר רַבִּי אַחָא הִתְחִיל אַבְרָהָם תָּמֵהַּ, אֵין הַדְּבָרִים הַלָּלוּ אֶלָּא דְבָרִים שֶׁל תֵּמַהּ, אֶתְמוֹל אָמַרְתָּ (בראשית כא, יב): כִּי בְיִצְחָק יִקָּרֵא לְךָ זָרַע, חָזַרְתָּ וְאָמַרְתָּ (בראשית כב, ב): קַח נָא אֶת בִּנְךָ, וְעַכְשָׁיו אַתְּ אָמַר לִי (בראשית כב, יב): אַל תִּשְׁלַח יָדְךָ אֶל הַנַּעַר, אֶתְמְהָא. אָמַר לוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא אַבְרָהָם (תהלים פט, לה): לֹא אֲחַלֵּל בְּרִיתִי וּמוֹצָא שְׂפָתַי לֹא אֲשַׁנֶּה. כְּשֶׁאָמַרְתִּי לְךָ קַח נָא אֶת בִּנְךָ, לֹא אָמַרְתִּי שְׁחָטֵהוּ, אֶלָּא וְהַעֲלֵהוּ, לְשֵׁם חִבָּה אָמַרְתִּי לָךְ, אֲסִקְתֵּיהּ וְקִיַּמְתָּ דְּבָרַי, וְעַתָּה אַחֲתִינֵיהּ.
[נסח אחר: משלו משל למלך שאמר לאוהבו העלה את בנך על שלחני, הביאו אותו אוהבו וסכינו בידו, אמר המלך וכי העלהו לאכלו אמרתי לך, העלהו אמרתי לך מפני חבתו. הדא הוא דכתיב (ירמיה יט, ה): ולא עלתה על לבי, זה יצחק. ]
Rabbi Aḥa said: Abraham began to express his astonishment, [saying to God]: ‘These events are nothing short of bewildering. Yesterday You said: “For it is through Isaac that will be called your descendants” (Genesis 21:12), then You said: “Take you your son […and offer him up]” (Genesis 22:2), and now You say to me: “Do not extend your hand against the lad”? This is bewildering.’ The Holy One blessed be He said to Abraham: ‘“I will not violate My covenant, nor alter the utterance of My lips” (Psalms 89:35) – when I said to you: “Take you your son,” I did not say: “Slaughter him,” but rather, “take him up.” I said this to you in affection. You have taken him up and fulfilled My words, now take him down.’
[Another version: They gave a parable of a king who said to his beloved one: "Bring your son up to my table." The beloved one brought him, with a knife in his hand. The king said to him: "Did I tell you to bring him up in order to slaughter him? I told you to bring him up because of my affection for him."
This is as it is written (Jeremiah 19:5) "It never entered my mind" – this refers to Isaac.]

Additionally, gemara Sanhedrin 107a teaches

אמר רב יהודה אמר רב לעולם אל יביא אדם עצמו לידי נסיון שהרי דוד מלך ישראל הביא עצמו לידי נסיון ונכשל אמר לפניו רבש"ע מפני מה אומרים אלהי אברהם אלהי יצחק ואלהי יעקב ואין אומרים אלהי דוד אמר אינהו מינסו לי ואת לא מינסית לי אמר לפניו רבש"ע בחנני ונסני שנאמר (תהלים כו, ב) בחנני ה' ונסני וגו'
Rav Yehuda says that Rav says: A person should never bring himself to undergo an ordeal, as David, king of Israel, brought himself to undergo an ordeal and failed. David said before God: Master of the Universe, for what reason does one say in prayer: God of Abraham, God of Isaac, and God of Jacob, and one does not say: God of David? God said to David: They have undergone ordeals before Me, and you have not undergone an ordeal before Me. David said before Him: Examine me and subject me to an ordeal, as it is stated: “Examine me, Lord, and subject me to an ordeal; try my kidneys and my heart” (Psalms 26:2).

The Artscroll comment states:

The Patriarchs earned the priviledge of having My name affixed to theirs because they withstood all the tests of faith to which they were subjected. Abraham was subjected to 10 tests (Avos 5:3 and Avos deRabbi Nassan 33:2). Isaac was ready and willing to be slaughtered as an offering at My behest (Bereshis 22). Jacob endured a life of suffering, yet he persevered in his faith (Rashi to Bereshis 43:14, Sanhedrin 111a). You David, on the other hand, have never been subjected to a test of faith as severe as those to which the Patriarchs were subjected.

Why did Yitzchak have to go through the Akkeida, and what exactly it revealed to the world regarding him?

+1 It's funny, I have a conundrum answering this; I have a long list of things he gained from it, from both the Chida and Ohr HaChaim, and iirc they both hold it wasn't a test for him. Does your interest in the benefit for Yitzchak stand on its own or is it only in the context of benefit deriving from the fact that it is a test?

I am reading this and wondering exactly how you claim this demonstrates it being a test for Yitzchak?

@RabbiKaii so why do we need to take a poor 37-year old man, tie, place on the altar, and he should passively accept all that?

I don't know, but if you want an explicit source that it was a test for Yitzchak, consider this Bet HaLevi

@RabbiKaii i find it very flat. Very religious, devoted, but flat. I could accept something along the lines that Yitzchak was a passive and yielding person and needed to learn the value of his own life... Thank you for finishing the translation.

I think there is some background to consider, which brings me back to my first question

@RabbiKaii I like the subject and certainly if you have any worthy thoughts - that's fine. However, if it was not a test for Yitzchak, then the possibility of opinion that Avraham failed the Akkeida test is much higher. If it was not a test for Yitzchak, then Avraham could practice his gevurah opposing Hashem's request and defending his son. However, that's against the Mishna Avos 5:3.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Arizal says Yitschak was misaken Adams Chait of ritzicha by the Akeida when he sacrificed his life for hashem.
(Arizal explains how each of the Avos were misaken different sins of Adam)
(Toras chida , Pnei dovid begining of Vaetza)

Could you give a source? Was there some mishap in the way that the Avos served Hashem prior to their tests?

@YDJ whats your 2nd question?

When Iyov was tested, the chachamim said that's because he served b'yirah, but after the test (which he failed) he served b'ahavah. Was there something similar, what did the test reveal about Yitzchak?
